# How can I get the renderings when using the Find-Item command?

Tags: powershell-extensions, powershell

I used `Find-Item` to get the items on my `sitecore_master_index`. Now, I want to get the presentation details of each item.

How can I do get each rendering/presentation details?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The output of `Find-Item` command is a `SearchResultItem` object. You need to call `GetItem()` on it first and then you can run commands which will return presentation details. I'm not sure exactly what you want to return but sample code goes as:

```
$criteria = @(
    ...
)
$props = @{
    Index = "sitecore_master_index"
    Criteria = $criteria
}
$searchResultItems = Find-Item @props

foreach ($searchResultItem in $searchResultItems) {
    $searchResultItem.GetItem() | Get-Rendering -FinalLayout
}
```

Comment: I tried running your sample code and the result is exactly what I'm looking. Thank you so much.